# imacro: SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag a

Tags: regex

I use this regex in imacro to strip ahref tag:

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var text=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; text.replace(/<a\b[^>]+>([^<]*(?:(?!</a)<[^<]*)*)</a>/g, '');")
```

but I got the error:

> SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag a

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an escape:

```
[..snip...]*)*)</a>/g, '');") 
                ^--here
```

That `/` terminates the regex pattern, leaving the rest as modifiers. You probably want:

```
[..snip...]*)*)<\/a>/g, '');") 
                ^---note the escape
```

instead.

Comment: Then it is two missings!